# Is Direction Derivative Projection of unit vector ?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

We know projection of u onto v is the vector

$proj_{v}u=(|u|cos\theta).\dfrac{v}{|v|}$

The directional derivative f(x,y) is differerntiable in an open region is
$ \nabla f .u =|\nabla f||u|cos \theta   $

$\because $u is unit vector $|u|=1$

$=|\nabla f|cos \theta$

If , yes then how it linked to rate change of f with arc length in particular .Any intutive way to understand .

Comment: That’s not the *definition* of a directional derivative, but an identity that holds at points where $f$ is differentiable thanks to linearity of the total derivative. Imagine taking vertical slices through the tangent plane.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be mixing up apples (scalars) and oranges (vectors):  we project a vector onto a vector and get a vector, but the directional derivative is a scalar.  Still, it's a good question because the formulas for **scalar** projection and the dot product version of the directional derivative do look similar.   This isn't coincidental.

The scalar projection of $\mathbf{v}$ onto the nonzero vector $\mathbf{u}$ is "defined" to be
$$
\mathrm{sproj}_{\mathbf{u}}\mathbf{v}= |\mathbf{v}| \cos\theta
$$
where $\theta$ is the angle between $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{u}$. (And if $\mathbf{v}$ is the zero vector it hardly matters what you make $\theta$.) This is also the same thing as 
$$
\mathbf{v} \cdot \frac{\mathbf{u}}{|\mathbf{u}|}.
$$
Either way, it's the length of the vector projection when acute, and its negative when obtuse.  And, this is all simpler when $\mathbf{u}$ is a unit vector.

If you believe all this, then the directional derivative is the scalar projection of the gradient onto the unit vector $\mathbf{u}$.  This comes from the identity
$$
D_\mathbf{u}f = \nabla f \cdot \mathbf{u} = |\nabla f| \cos \theta = \mathrm{sproj}_{\mathbf{u}}\nabla f
$$
where $\theta$ is the angle between $\nabla f$ and $\mathbf{u}$.